# Reverse Proxy Solr behind Apache Web server

Tags: solr, reverse-proxy

I have an existing apache web server (2.2.15), configured with various security details (https only / authentication / authorization / etc.). I can rely on this server to handle the access requirements to my solr installation.

I have a basic 'example' solr instance up and running on a separate machine. (Solr 4.8.0 )

I want to be able to redirect the url `https://myserver/department/team/search/....` to the Solr instance running on another (private) machine `http://solrserver:8983/`

I have configured the apache server with:

```
ProxyPass /department/team/search/ http://solserver:8983/
ProxyPassReverse /department/team/search/ http://solserver:8983/
```

I have some success with this, the https is being handled, the authentication/access is handled, and so on.

When I browse to the the url it is even loading up the basic solr page, but the page, internally, has the following:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var app_config = {};

  app_config.solr_path = '\/solr';
  app_config.core_admin_path = '\/admin\/cores';

  </script>
```

And that (I believe) is causing the JavaScript code to try to call:

```
 https://myserver/solr/admin/cores?wt=json&indexInfo=false&_=1399485239437
```

Instead of

```
 https://myserver/department/team/search/solr/admin/cores?wt=json&indexInfo=false&_=1399485239437
```

I believe these two values are configurable ( `app_config.solr_path` and `app_config.core_admin_path` ) but I cannot find out how/where to do it......

Questions:

1. How do I change the values set for the `app_config.solr_path` and `app_config.core_admin_path`?
2. Alternatively, this may be the wrong way to do this entirely, is there a better way to do it? (though the authentication/security provided by the apache webserver is perfect right now....)

Comment: Did you work out a solution to this problem?  I just encountered the same symptoms and ran into your question as I was looking for solutions.

Comment: @PeterMurray - I started looking in to the proxy-html module of nginx - one where you can do search/replace in the content returned to the client,  but that lead to other sorts of problems. My final solution was to add multiple instances of nginx with the solr proxy running on it's own port, and matching the URL paths on both nodes - i.e. a dedicated proxy for the solr. That particylar server is no longer operating, aand I have moved to elasticsearch, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName solr.xyz.com.br  
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests off   

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^\/solr(.*)$ $1 [L,R]

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/solr/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/solr/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I believe this works for you because the path part of the Solr URL is the same on both the apache server, and the solr server. In my case, I need to redirect a long path `/department/team/search/` to an empty path `/`, and it is internal references inside the pages to javascript and ajax calls that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be out of context, but I would recommend replacing Apache with NGINX, much much simpler configuraiton. All you need is the following in `nginx.conf`:

```
location /solr/select {
  proxy_pass http://YourSolrServer:8983/solr/select;
  proxy_buffering on;
}
```

You can change the first `/solr/select` with whatever path you want (eg. /department/team/search/). So simple, so elegant.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ajax-solr/pLtYfm83I98

Comment: I actually exprimented with nginx (and since I asked this question a couple of years ago, I have become much more experienced with nginx). Unfortunately the problem still remains.... the Solr code needs to have internal references "mapped" from one URL path to another path. Your answer has the same paths in the nginx host and the `YourSolrServer` host (the path `/solr/select` ) but in my case, the nginx has the path `department/team/search` and the solr server has the path `/`.